# i want to check that the time difference between the user date,time and current date is of 24hours

Tags: php

this is my code and i want to check that if the difference is less then 24 hours then print no otherwise print yes

problem statement - i am making a booking website in which user have to book 24vhours in advance so i have done this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$timestamp = strtotime($date . ' ' . $time); 

// getting current date 
$cDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

// Getting the value of old date + 24 hours
$oldDate = $timestamp; // 86400 seconds in 24 hrs

if(($cDate-$oldDate)<=86400)
{
    echo yes; 
}
else
{
    echo no;
    //outputs no
}

?>
```

Comment: Describe your problem

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>= 86400`

Comment: try using echo "yes" and echo "no"